# Difference between saying "error redirected to output channel" vs "output redirected to error channel"?

Tags: io-redirection

https://community.unix.com/t/difference-between-2-1-and-2-1/392167

I was reading this post.

> ls name 2>&1 makes bash run ls with its stderr assigned to the same stream as its stdout (not the other way around, as you state).

Saw this. I'm wondering how is that different in a higher level of abstraction? Don't both throw their results in same file and that's all that matters?

Comment: Not if you have additional redirections

Comment: So `2>&1 > foo` is not going to be the same as `1>&2 > foo`

Comment: If you're in a context where stdout is going to file1.txt and stderr is going to file2.txt, and you use `2>&1` on a command, then that command's stdout and stderr will both go to file1.txt (the one that *was* just stdout), not to file2.txt (the one that *was* stderr). That's the distinction that's being made.